# How can I "close" or "delete" my own question?

Tags: discussion

Recently, I asked a question, and after realising that it was beyond my ability, wanted to "close" or "delete" my question. I don't know if its possible or good practice.

Comment: "Recently, I asked a question, and after realising that it was beyond my ability" Isn't that why everyone asks questions? To gain knowledge they did not have before?  If you must delete it, the delete button is right next to the edit button, below the question tags. I highly recommend against people deleting posts just for the sake of it, it will start you on the road to question asking restrictions and sooner or later a ban.